# MATLAB R2014b: Rendering plots with lines in the same place

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

Since version R2014b, MATLAB now renders graphics nicely anti-aliased (finally!)

However, this causes a glitch in the way it displays some of my figures. If I plot a line, use `hold on` and then plot another line in exactly the same place with a different colour, the line appears in a mottled combination of both colours. In the past, the line would simply appear as the *last* colour that was plotted in that location.

Here's an example of a trace in blue, with some sections (the steeper bits) showing a green line. In previous MATLAB versions, the green lines would be continuous, but now some of the blue line shows through.

[image]

Is there a neat way to work around this in the new version, or do I have to ensure that I remove any existing lines before plotting in the same place?

Comment: Please include the code used to generate the plot

Comment: You probably want to remove the previous lines anyway.  MATLAB uses vector graphics, so even data that is completely obscured still adds to the complexity and processing time of the figure.

Comment: For your particular application, you may want to use a single plot object with per-vertex color control.  For that, see the section "Specifying edge colors" in the documentation for `patch`.

Answer (score 0):

When overplotting, the new anti aliasing plots can have some bleed through, try

`set(gcf,'GraphicsSmoothing','off')`

To see if it restores the functionality you're used to.

Ref:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157758-how-do-i-turn-off-antialiasing-in-matlab-r2014b